# What can explain the difference of temperature between Ryzen 3200G Pro and a Ryzen 3200G?

Tags: cooling, temperature, amd-ryzen

I love silence and I really dislike noise.

For this reason I bought a passive cooler for a 3200 Ryzen CPU.

The temperature is a little high in my opinion

```
temp1:        +60.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)
```

On another PC I have the same passive cooler, the case is the same. But the CPU is 3200 Pro
and the temperature go not over 40° (is usually 32°-35°!)

Why this difference?

I am using Linux Slackware in the "hot" CPU and Debian in the "cold" CPU.

Comment: Why do you believe 60C is high? it seems like the one that is 40C might be running too cool. The reality is sensors can be unreliable and unless there is a really reason to be concerned, you shouldn’t be concerned.

Comment: Is not high, but 40° is better